# PC restaged, installed VS2017, Attunity driver for Tdata, package starts, finished, canceled

Tags: ssis, teradata, sql-server-data-tools, attunity

I have an SSIS package that ran fine under SSDT for VS2012 and an earlier version of the Attunity drivers for Teradata.

On my restaged Windows7 PC, I installed VS2017, MS VS Tools for Applications 2017, and MS Connector for Tdata by Attunity 5.0.

However, when I try to execute an ADO.NET script task on a connection to the Tdata server, the immediate window says:

```
SSIS Package "C:\...\main.dtsx" starting.
SSIS Package "C:\...\main.dtsx" finished: Canceled.
```

And the task didn't run on Tdata.  When I click on 'Test Connection' in the Tdata Connection Manager Editor, it says

```
Test connection succeeded.
```

I have another package that copies data from Tdata to SQL Server just fine, but it doesn't execute procedures on Tdata with `isQueryStoredProcedure=True` and a `SQL Statement` like

```
call db.usp_ssis()
```

The `Parse Query` button on the SQL Task says

```
TITLE: SQL Task
The query parsed correctly.
```

Is there something else I need to change in my package to get the SQL Task executing a Tdata procedure to run?

---

Found this in their help file:

```
Connector Overview
...
Version Support

n         Teradata Parallel Transporter API (TPT API) with the Load, Export and Stream TPT operators. The following TPT API versions are supported:
–        14.10
–        15
–        15.10
```

but I've installed Teradata Client 16.10.
Do I need to downgrade to TPT 15.10 to run SSIS packages?

---

also, if I only use Tdata as a source for data transfer tasks, it works fine.  When I try to execute a SQL Task against a Tdata connection or transfer data to a Tdata destination, it gives me the `starting/canceled` message.

I'm currently downgrading to TTU v15.10

---

[this helped](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50fe3448-20ad-4950-8fbf-8ffd8a6d745c/ssis-packages-not-executing-within-ssdt?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50fe3448-20ad-4950-8fbf-8ffd8a6d745c/ssis-packages-not-executing-within-ssdt?forum=ssdt)

*Even though v4.0 is required to be installed to allow the designer in VS2015 to access and use the connector/Sources/Destinations, you still need the version specific to the SSIS TargetServerVersion that you're using installed as well.*

So I'm trying TTU v16 again with the SSIS package targeting SQL Server 2017

---

got it to work with VS2017 on Win7, TTU v16 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers after setting package TargetServerVersion to 2017

---

Actually, it still doesn't work.  I need the Attunity drivers to write to a Tdata destination component, and I've installed the 32- and 64-bit versions 2.0 through 5.0, and none of them work.  When I click on `Test Connection` in the Tdata Connection Manager Editor, it says:

```
Failed to establish an ODBC connection with the database server. Verify that the Teradata ODBC Driver for Windows x86 is installed properly. SqlState = IM002 Message = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
 (package)
```

TTU List Products says:

```
Version                 Display Name
14.10.00.03           Teradata Visual Explain 14.10.0.3
15.10.01.00           Teradata GSS Client nt-x8664  15.10.1
16.10.0.0           .NET Data Provider for Teradata 16.10
16.10.00.00           Shared ICU Libraries for Teradata 16.10
16.10.00.00           Shared ICU Libraries for Teradata nt-x8664 16.10
16.10.00.00           Teradata Named Pipes Access Module 16.10
16.10.00.00           Teradata Named Pipes Access Module nt-x8664 16.10
16.10.00.00           Teradata OLE DB Access Module 16.10
16.10.00.00           Teradata OLE DB Access Module nt-x8664 16.10
16.10.00.02           Teradata BTEQ 16.10.0.2
16.10.00.02           Teradata FastLoad 16.10.0.2
16.10.00.02           Teradata SQL Assistant 16.10.0.2
16.10.00.03           ODBC Driver for Teradata 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           ODBC Driver for Teradata nt-x8664 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           Teradata Data Connector 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           Teradata Data Connector nt-x8664 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           Teradata FastExport 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           Teradata MultiLoad 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           Teradata Parallel Transporter Base 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           Teradata Parallel Transporter Base nt-x8664 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           Teradata Parallel Transporter Stream 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           Teradata Parallel Transporter Stream nt-x8664 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.03           Teradata TPump 16.10.0.3
16.10.00.05           Teradata CLIv2 16.10.0.5
16.10.00.05           Teradata CLIv2 nt-x8664 16.10.0.5
16.10.00.05           Teradata GSS Administration Package nt-i386  16.10.0.5
16.10.00.05           Teradata GSS Administration Package nt-x8664  16.10.0.5
16.10.05.00           Teradata Tools and Utilities - Base 16.10.05
```

---

had to downgrade to TTU 15, couldn't get 16 to work.

Comment: That was a wild ride. Did you get this working now (it looks like you did). If so, can you add the steps you took as a new answer here just in case someone else stumbles into all these mismatching libraries issues in the future. It sounds like you found the magic combination.

Answer (score 0):

Credit for this answer really belongs to `evan.morgoch S&C Electric Canada Ltd` but what I did on my newly restaged PC was attempt to install the latest versions of Visual Studio (2017), SSDT (or SSDT-BI) for VS2017, TTU (16), and the Attunity drivers (5.0).

My existing package wouldn't run with those versions until I changed the TargetServerVersion property in the package to 2017.  Our environment does not include SQL Server 2017 (not sure what our latest version is, maybe 2012?) but from the package engine's point of view, it doesn't matter.